# Why isn't my Switch statement prompting for user input exiting properly?

Tags: powershell

I have written a Switch statement where, if the user inputs anything other than Y or N, the script should keep prompting until they enter either one of those letters.

```
$Prompt = Read-host "Should I display the file contents c:\test for you? (Y | N)" 
Switch ($Prompt)
     {
       Y {Get-ChildItem c:\test}
       N {Write-Host "User canceled the request"}
       Default {$Prompt = read-host "Would you like to remove C:\SIN_Store?"}
     }
```

What happens now, however, is that when the user inputs anything other than Y or N, they get prompted again. But when they type *any* letter the second time, the script just exits. It doesn't ask the user for their input anymore. Is it possible to accomplish this using Switch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do in the default in your code, but as per your question, you want to put it in a loop:

```
do{

$Prompt = Read-host "Should I display the file contents c:\test for you? (Y | N)" 
Switch ($Prompt)
 {
   Y {Get-ChildItem c:\test}
   N {Write-Host "User canceled the request"}
   Default {continue}
 }

} while($prompt -notmatch "[YN]")
```

Powershell way of doing this:

```
$caption="Should I display the file contents c:\test for you?"
$message="Choices:"
$choices = @("&Yes","&No")

$choicedesc = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription] 
$choices | foreach  { $choicedesc.Add((New-Object "System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription" -ArgumentList $_))} 


$prompt = $Host.ui.PromptForChoice($caption, $message, $choicedesc, 0)

Switch ($prompt)
     {
       0 {Get-ChildItem c:\test}
       1 {Write-Host "User canceled the request"}
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't piping that input anywhere.  You can do this with a recursive function:

```
Function GetInput
{
$Prompt = Read-host "Should I display the file contents c:\test for you? (Y | N)" 
Switch ($Prompt)
     {
       Y {Get-ChildItem c:\test}
       N {Write-Host "User canceled the request"}
       Default {GetInput}
     }
}
```